The $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3) $ subgroup of the compact Lie group $ G_2 $
I'm interested in the $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3)  $ subgroup of the compact Lie group $ G_2 $. Is there any proper, positive dimensional subgroup of $ G_2 $ that contains $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3)  $ (if not then the $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3)  $ subgroup is said to be Lie Primitive) ? Any proper, positive dimensional subgroup would be the normalizer of some connected subgroup of rank at most $ 2 $. It seems very unlikely that such a subgroup of $ G_2 $ could contain $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3)  $.
To give some non-examples illustrating the distinction here, $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3)  $ is a subgroup of $ SU(6) $ and $ SO(7) $, but is not Lie Primitive in either group, since $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3)  \subset Sp(3) \subset SU(6) $ and $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3)  \subset G_2 \subset SO(7) $.
Looking at table PE of https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1999-36-01/S0273-0979-99-00771-5/ it seems that all Lie Primitive subgroups are labelled with a P, but there is not a P label in the table for the $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3)  $ subgroup. Am I missing some obvious positive dimensional intermediate subgroup $ H $ such that $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3)  \subset H \subset G_2 $? (to be clear there is an intermediate subgroup $ PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3) :2 \cong Aut(PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3) )\cong G_2(2) $, but it is not positive dimesional)
If not, is there just a mistake in the table in the paper?

Isn't $PSU(3, 3)$ noncompact? Or are you referring to $PSU_3(\mathbb{F}_3)$?
